# Envelope Signed Notification

Tags: docusignapi

I create a pdf on our system and then pass that to docusign for the user to sign. I want to automatically download and save the signed envelopes in our system. Is there a way for docusign to send a post request after the document is signed?

Right now, I randomly (every other hour) connect to docusign and check if the envelope is signed using the docusign api, but this is really not optimal. There are a lot of users who view the pdf in docusign and decide they don't want to sign the document.

Comment: See this page, you want DocuSign Connect:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "DocuSign Connect" feature is designed to do exactly that -- send a POST to an endpoint you specify, in real-time, as specified Envelope events occur. Basically it works like this: you build a "listener" app (i.e., a web page that will receive POSTs from Connect), you configure Connect (within your DocuSign account (**Preferences >> Connect**) to specify the endpoint of your "listener" and select which Envelope events you want your listener to receive notifications for, etc., and once that Connect configuration is enabled, DocuSign will send a POST to your listener endpoint whenever the specified Envelope event(s) occur.

The DocuSign Connect Service Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf) describes Connect and how to configure/use it -- I'd suggest that you start by reviewing the guide, and post any additional questions here on SO if you run into any issues implementing Connect.

Comment: I got it working but there is one problem. Docusign can't send a post request to the URLs that have a port number in them. I tried with     `https://xxx/yyy` and it worked fine. Then I tried with `https://xxx:8443/yyy` and I didn't get the request. Any help?

Comment: Yes, that's true -- DocuSign Connect will always send notifications to the "standard/default" port numbers.  i.e., for HTTPS -- port 443, and for HTTP (which will work in DEMO only) -- port 80. To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible for Connect to deliver messages if you specify any port number in the endpoint URL.

Comment: Thank you. Will you change this in the future? Or should we code a workaround?

Comment: It's been this way for years, so I wouldn't expect it to change anytime soon.

Comment: (If my answer above satisfies your question, can you please mark it as accepted?  This will allow others to potentially benefit from the info in the future here on SO. Thanks!)

Comment: Is there anyway to have a dynamic url for the publish url? Let's say I want it to end with "/${envelope-id}"

Comment: That's not possible if you're just configuring DocuSign Connect at the Account level, by using the web console UI (Preferences >> Connect). However, you could specify the "eventNotification" parameter for each Envelope in the Create Envelope API request -- this would allow you to specify a unique URL for each Envelope, because you'd be specifying the URL as part of each Create Envelope API request.